# using None in Python

Tags: python, duplicates

i have a directory with matching duplicate files.  However these duplicate files have a randomly generated digits number behind the .txt which allows them to co-exist in the same directory.

aaaabbbbcccc.txt.12345678

aaaabbbbcccc.txt.34567890

qqqqwwwwrrrr.txt.98765432,

qqqqwwwwrrrr.txt.54321987

At the end of the day all i need is one of the two files(with the same name) and the information within them. I am capable of retrieving the data within the file. I have thousands of files to remove in this directory.

A co-worker has suggested this:

```
prev_base = None
for rs_file in sorted(os.listdir('.') ):
    base_rs_file = rs_file[:-7]
    if base_rs_file == prev_base:
      os.unlink( rs_file)
    else:
      prev_base = base_rs_file
```

i am not sure I am fully understanding how this snippet of code actually works.  I understand what is happening up until the 'if' statement.  Any help would be great.

Thanks,
Shane

Comment: Your indentation is probably off.. the indentation of `else` should be he same level as `if` - Then it would make more sense - If `prev_base` is not set, or not the same as the current file, then update the prev_base. If it is, delete the current file.

Comment: While `for` loops can have `else` clauses, an `else` on a `for` loop will not do what you expect. The `else` is almost certainly supposed to be indented to the level of the `if`.

Comment: Thank you - sorry, the indentation was my error. Thanks for the response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See comments inline

```
# initialize the variable to None, it could have been "" also..
prev_base = None

#Iterates through the directory containing the files sorted. 
#It assumes that you are   running the script in same directory as files.

for rs_file in sorted(os.listdir('.') ):

# Extract the identical part from each basename.
# Example: for qqqqwwwwrrrr.txt.54321987, base_rs_file=qqqqwwwwrrrr.txt
```

There is a problem here, it should be **-9** not -7

```
    base_rs_file = rs_file[:-9]

# Compare to previous basename. This is why prev_base had to be initialized. Otherwise #   test would return an error

    if base_rs_file == prev_base:

# The basename has already been found, the file is removed. 
# The method unlink() removes (deletes) the file path

      os.unlink( rs_file)
else:

# if the basename has not been found previously, value is assigned to prev_base

      prev_base = base_rs_file
```

Comment: I think this line base_rs_file = rs_file[:-7] should be base_rs_file = rs_file[:-9]

Comment: That is great! Thank you for the walk through. I really needed to have a better understanding on how this worked. Great help :)

Comment: @Shane_McC : you may want to change the status to answered